# Crashlytics Issue When GCP API Key Restriction Applied

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, crashlytics-android

I have an Android app with Crashlytics set up properly. I was getting Crashlytics crash events. But once I applied the GCP API Key restriction with [Android App + App package & SHA1], Crashlytics events stopped (I tested with forced crashing using "throw RuntimeException"). Even after undoing/reverting/clearing all the restrictions on the GCP key I am still not receiving any crashes now. This has happened to two of my projects now. Any idea what's wrong?

Here is the snapshot of the API Key restriction page where I had made Android related changes:

[image: This is the GCP API Key restriction page where I had applied the restrictions]

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue. It is embarrassing but I will leave it here for others making the same mistake.

Firebase uploads the crash which has occurred in the current session only once app is relaunched in the next session. I had added the forced crash code in one of the initial activities (activity after the splash screen to be precise) and I was assuming the upload must be happening magically in the next session during the splash screen delay. But *boy*, was I wrong! Once I removed the forced crash code and ran the app, I received the crashes.

So gist -- If you are testing Crashlytics with forced crashes, fix the crash and then relaunch the app to get all the crashes.